# NSUserActivity not getting indexed on osx

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsuseractivity

I'm trying to add my own activity to Spotlight search results on osx 10.11. But after a lot of tries I couldn't got to be in Spotlight search results not by keywords search, not by title search.

```
{
    self.userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@"Reverse DNS keyword"];

    self.userActivity.title = @"Some title";
    self.userActivity.keywords = [NSSet setWithArray: @[@"Some keywords"]];
    self.userActivity.eligibleForSearch = YES;
    self.userActivity.eligibleForHandoff = YES;
    self.userActivity.eligibleForPublicIndexing = YES;
    self.userActivity.userInfo = @{@"name" : @"Some name"};
    self.userActivity.delegate = self;
    self.userActivity.requiredUserInfoKeys =[NSSet setWithArray: @[@"name"]];
    self.userActivity.needsSave = YES;

    [self.userActivity becomeCurrent];

    NSApp.userActivity = self.userActivity;
}

- (void)userActivityWillSave:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
{
     userActivity.userInfo = @{@"name" : @"Some name"};
}
```

Also I've updated Info.plist with NSUserActivityTypes array and item from the initWithActivityType: argument

Also I've noticed that in Console sometime appears messages:

```
16/09/2016 13:14:49.731 Caching encoded userInfo to use until we are marked dirty again (UAUserActivity.m #1567)
16/09/2016 13:14:49.731 Returning cached encoded userInfo (UAUserActivity.m #1508)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a searched a lot, eventually I found answer on my question in [TN2416](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2416/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016269-CH1-SEARCH_API_BEST_PRACTICES-NSUSERACTIVITY_API):

```
**Are these new Search APIs available on OS X?**

CoreSpotlight and the search functionality of NSUserActivity are not supported on OS X.  However, web search results may be shown on OS X.
```